# Any open source sub-daily weather data other than Jena?

Tags: open-data, evaporation, weatherdata

I am looking for observed sub-daily weather data (as 1d time series) which must include temperature, humidity, solar radiation and wind speed for a any location on earth. Currently I am aware of [Jena city](https://www.bgc-jena.mpg.de/wetter/Weatherstation.pdf) data which is available as open source. Can anyone mention another source?

Comment: I think more details may be beneficial. Is there a particular region that you are interested in? What resolution of observations are you looking for? Are you interested in direct observations, reanalysis, or forecast data?

Comment: I am looking for observed time series data for any region of earth. I have also edited the question.

Comment: @AtherCheema https://www.foto-webcam.eu/webcam/wallackhaus/ would this work for you ?

Comment: @AtherCheema https://wegenernet.org/portal/ then there is that

Comment: @AtherCheema Then there is Izana - https://izana.aemet.es/meteorological-data-graphs/

Comment: @gansub, thank you very much. Does the 2nd and 3rd links provide some way to download time-series data? I did not see an option?

Comment: @AtherCheema You will  have to ask them. I have not actually used them in a project. You can contact them and find out

Comment: @AtherCheema if it is ok with you i can summarize the three links in an answer.

Comment: @gunsub Yes sure. I will accept the answer. It might be helpful for future readers if you add location and frequency of available data in the answer.

Comment: In case you could be happy also with reanalysis data (model outputs "adjusted" with observed data), there are additional interesting datasets, as for the ERA5 (https://www.ecmwf.int/en/forecasts/datasets/reanalysis-datasets/era5) that offers all the main meteorological variables at 30km resolution for hourly time steps between 1979 to present days.